# Appending pandas series to the left of index zero

Tags: python, pandas, append, series, pad

I'm trying to select portions of a pandas data series  `yf`  according to left limit  `a0`  and right limit  `b0` .

If the left limit is negative, I want to pad the difference with zeros so the resulting series would have the desired length, like this:

```
if a0<0: ycr = pd.Series([0]*(abs(a0))).append(yf[:b0])
```

but this is returning:

```
Series([], Name: 1, dtype: float64)
```

and no more information is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the source *Series* as:

```
lst = np.arange(10,20)
yf = pd.Series(lst + 5, index = lst)
```

so that it contains:

```
10    15
11    16
12    17
13    18
14    19
15    20
16    21
17    22
18    23
19    24
dtype: int32
```

(the left column is the index, and the right - actual values).

Then, to create an output *Series* composed of 3 zeroes and
then 5 initial elements of *yf* I ran:

```
a0 = -3; b0 = 5
ycr = pd.Series([0]*(abs(a0))).append(yf[:b0])
```

and got:

```
0      0
1      0
2      0
10    15
11    16
12    17
13    18
14    19
dtype: int64
```

Then I performed another test, on the source *Series* created
with the default index (consecutive integers from *0*):

```
yf = pd.Series(lst + 5)
```

This time the result is:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
0    15
1    16
2    17
3    18
4    19
dtype: int64
```

(the only difference is in the index column, as I expected).

So, as you can see, your code works as expected.
Probably there is something wrong with your source data.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, this works. My issue was with the dimensions of the resulting series. Sorry about this.